# Slice of a Set can be Empty?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I am considering a slice of a set in the context of product measure and soon to be discussed the Fubini's theorem.

Consider two probability spaces: $(\Omega_1,F_1,P_1),(\Omega_2,F_2,P_2).$

Let $E\in F_1\times F_2$ in the usual sense that it belongs to the smallest sigma-algebra of subsets of $\Omega_1\times\Omega_2$.

Define a slice of a set at $\omega_1\in\Omega_1$ as:

$$E_{\omega_1}\equiv\{\omega_2:(\omega_1,\omega_2)\in E\}.$$

If $E=A_1\times A_2$ where $A_i\in F_i$, then the slice is either empty or $A_2$.

I get it can be $A_2$, but how can it be empty? Does this happen when $A_2$ is the degenerate case of being empty set?

On a related note, define $L=\{E\in F_1\times F_2:E_{\omega_1}\in F_2\}$. Why does $L$ contain all the rectangles by the above observation?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Omega =\Omega '=(0,1)$. Then, in $\Omega \times \Omega '$, consider $$A=\{0.5\}\times (0,1).$$ Then, of course $$A^{0.25}=\{\omega' \in \Omega '\mid (0.25,\omega ')\in A\}=\varnothing .$$

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, your response does not address all of my questions.